# Lambertian surface and radiant intensity

Tags: visible-light, reflection, surface-diffusion

I am sure this question has been answered a gazillion times but I still struggle to find an answer that clears out all my doubt.

Assuming a Lambertian surface $A$ is illuminated by a light source $S$. The angle between the surface normal $\vec{n}$ and the direction of the light source (from $S$ to $x$ on $A$) is $\theta_i$.

I understood that the radiant intensity received at $x$ is $I_i = I_0\cos\theta_i$, following the Lambert's cosine law.

I also understood that the light reflected by the surface $A$ at x follows the lambert's cosine law, and as such $I_r = I_i\cos\theta_r$ where $\theta_r$ coresponds to the angle between the normal to the surface $\vec{n}$ and the observer's direction (from $x$ to a camera/ observer).

As such I would guess that I could write $I_r = I_0\cos\theta_i\cos\theta_r$. From that perspective, I further understood that the maximum reflected radiant intensity is always in the direction of the normal $\vec{n}$ to the surface $A$.

I am sure there is something wrong, as I am regulary wrong, but I really would like to understand what is incorrect. I understand why the apparent brightness (radiance) is independant from the observer position but would like to understand where I am wrong regarding the "reflected" radiant intensity.

I really thank you for your help, and apologies for asking yeat another question on Lambert cosine law.

Kind regards,

Charles